# How to install and run wearable apps?

Tags: java, android, wear-os, watch-face-api

I have created a watch face for android wear. I followed [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) and generated signed apk. But there are two generated apks under my folder as shown in image:

[image]

So, if I install mobile-release.apk then will it work for wear companion app? Can anyone help me how to install and run wearable app?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable debugging mode on your wear device as described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html). After enabling the debugging mode, you will be able to select from Android Studio the watch in order to install your watch face.

After installing, don't forget to actually select the watch face as being the current one (long tap on main screen of the watch and select your watch face).

Answer (score 0):

wear apk is a part of phone apk, put wear apk in the raw folder of phone apk, and write a desc xml in phone apk,
wear apk will auto install when the phone apk is installed on the phone device.